# Enabling dashboards for filebeat

Tags: filebeat, elk

I am trying to develop more visibility around AWS. I'd really like to use the prebuilt dashboards that come with filebeat, but I seem to constantly run into issues with the visualizations for elb and vpcflow logs. My configuration looks like this:

```
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
setup.kibana:
  host: "localhost:9243"
  protocol: "https"
  username: "kibana_user"
  password: "kibana_password"
setup.dashboards.enabled: true
setup.dashboards.directory: ${path.config}/kibana
setup.ilm.enabled: false
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  protocol: "https"
  username: "elastic_user"
  password: "password"
  indices:
  - index: "cloudtrail-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
    when.contains:
      event.dataset: "aws.cloudtrail"
  - index: "elb-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
    when.contains:
      event.dataset: "aws.elb"
  - index: "vpc-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
    when.contains:
      event.dataset: "aws.vpc"
processors:
  - add_fields:
      target: my_env
      fields:
        environment: development
```

In my dashboards directory I changed the `filebeat-*` index to
`vpc-*` for `Filebeat-aws-vpcflow-overview.json`, `cloudtrail-*` for `filebeat-aws-cloudtrail.json` and `elb-*` for `Filebeat-aws-elb-overview.json`. The cloudtrail dashboard works just fine. I only run into issues with the `elb` and `vpcflow` visualizations. None of elb requests visualizations work. The top IP addresses for vpcflow logs do not work either. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular situation if you don't use the deafault `filebeaat-*` index there are issues getting the prebuilt dashboards to spin up. I dropped the custom indexing that I had in my configuration and I was able to get the dashboards to load properly.